# Variance inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

Why does the following hold? For a random variable X with finite necessary moments,

$E(|X|) \leq \sqrt{Var(X)}+|E(X)|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just Jensen's inequality for the square root function $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $. Since $ f $ is concave, you know $ \mathbb E[f(X)] \leq f(\mathbb E[X]) $. Applying this to the random variable $ (X - \mathbb E[X])^2 $ gives

$$ \sigma_X = \sqrt{\operatorname{var}(X)} = \sqrt{\mathbb E[(X - \mathbb E[X])^2]} \geq \mathbb E[|X - \mathbb E[X]|] $$
$$ \geq \mathbb E[|X| - |\mathbb E[X]|] = \mathbb E[|X|] - |\mathbb E[X]| $$

where the last inequality uses the reverse triangle inequality $ |a-b| \geq ||a| - |b|| \geq |a| - |b| $.